# Why was the veal q removed from HNQ?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, hnq

I see that the veal q was also removed from HNQ https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/49953/revisions

Why?

Answer (score -1):

Similarly, [the reasons here explain](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4675/11643) that we're trying to curb extraneous mod efforts.

Differently, there's quite a few flags mostly along the lines "upset the OP doesn't seem genuine", on the question and the OP's self answer and even some comments. We also opted to lock it for a day, since it's becoming a "content dispute" that might motivate a meta post of its own along the lines "what does the community expect us to do when this happens?".

The volume of activity that needed mod intervention on the post wasn't terribly burdensome, but people are flagging the OP's question, answer, and comments as "spam" and "other" with messages that he's trolling, etc. To be clear, we're on the same page with not really liking his answer and belligerence in accepting the evidence in the other answers, but he's not really breaking any rules, so we're at a loss what the flaggers expect.